# How to control subdirectory compiling order of cmake?

Tags: compilation, cmake, subdirectory

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(third)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(utils)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(rpc)
```

But the directory 'rpc' will be compiled before directory 'utils', actually the 'rpc' is depends on 'utils', so I will get a link error.

How can I make the 'rpc' compiling after 'utils'?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure rpc is compiled before utils? What is the error message?

Comment: You are right, 'rpc' is compiled after 'utils', but need link 'libutils.a'. After compiling 'utils', the command 'make install' has not been done.

Comment: how does rpc get at the header files of utils so that it will compile prior to link?

Answer (score 10):

When you use [target_link_libraries()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) function and pass it other target name, CMake automatically sets this target as a dependency. You can also use [add_dependencies()](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) to specify dependencies manually.

Also note that order of sources compilation have nothing to do with your problem. Link errors (i guess, you are seeing "undefined reference" ones) are because you aren't linking your targets properly.

Comment: I agree and just wanted to add the general rule that a header/include dependency most likely needs also a link dependency. And the possibility of [Cyclic Dependencies of Static Libraries](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html#cyclic-dependencies-of-static-libraries). And one hint that adding `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE 1)` to the main `CMakeLists.txt` helped me analyzing my dependency problems.

Answer (score 6):

if the 'rpc' is depends on 'utils':

utils CMAKELISTS.txt

```
project(utils)
add_library (utils SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCE_LIST})
```

rpc CMAKELISTS.txt

```
project(rpc)
add_library (rpc SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCE_LIST})
# must add this command to scan dependencies of target rpc
add_dependencies (rpc utils)
target_link_libraries (${TEST_SOURCE_FILE_NAME} libutils.so)
```

Comment: why  do you need to explicitly call add_dependencies? wouldn't target_link_libraries create it implicitly for you?

Answer (score 2):

- I have the same question with you.
- I have open source libs —— jthread and jrtplib. I want to build them by a main CmakeList.text so I make a folder like:

```sh
cpp
├─jrtplib
│  ├─src
│  └─CMakeFiles.txt
├─jthread
│    ├─src
│    └─CMakeFiles.txt
└─CMakeFiles.txt
```

and cpp/CMakeFiles.txt like:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)


set(JTHREAD_ENABLED 1)

# 包含子项目。

add_subdirectory ("jthread")
add_subdirectory ("jrtplib")
```

but build error, it build jrtplib first, I think "jr" > "jt", so build jrtplib first, and it can't find libjthread.so , so **target_link_libraries** error
I find a solution :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓  attention ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑  attention ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

set(JTHREAD_ENABLED 1)
# copy jthread/src/*.h to C:/thirdParty/include/jthread 
set(JTHREAD_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/thirdParty/include")
set(JTHREAD_LIBRARIES "libjthread.so")


# 包含子项目。
add_subdirectory (jthread)
add_subdirectory (jrtplib)
```

- set **xx_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY** can set library build in main cmake_build folder, so jrtplib can find libjthread.so .
- build success ...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the project named "third" is independent however "utils" depends upon "rpc". Try the following code for a sequential build

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(third)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(utils "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/utils_build")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(rpc "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/rpc_build")
```

this will make a "_build" directory in your given build directory. and will copy the binaries there. For more information try

```
cmake --help-command ADD_SUBDIRECTORY
```